# How do I query mongo on exact day

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

Here's my SQL query

```
SELECT customer_id, verification_start_time, address_scoring 
from under_writing_limits 
where day(verification_start_time) = 25
```

But my data is in MongoDB, usually I query on pandas, but I can't today because my data is getting bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
var myDate="25-01-2001";
myDate=myDate.split("-");
var newDate=myDate[1]+"/"+myDate[0]+"/"+myDate[2];
var date1 = new Date(newDate).getTime()

var myDate="25-07-2018";
myDate=myDate.split("-");
var newDate=myDate[1]+"/"+myDate[0]+"/"+myDate[2];
var date2 = new Date(newDate).getTime()


db.under_writing_limits.find(
  { verification_start_time: { $gte: date1, $lte: date2 } },
  { customer_id: 1, verification_start_time: 1, address_scoring: 1 }
)
```

Comment: The `verification_start_time` is timestamp, not number
I asking only if the date is 25

Comment: @NabihBawazir You can convert 25 to timestamp and then match with the `verification_start_time`

Comment: That is my question

Comment: @NabihBawazir you need to specify exact date **25-02-2011** something like this because 25 is not a date... its a day

Comment: 25 every month for 2001 to 2018 ?

Comment: you mean 25-01-2001 to 25-01-2018?

Comment: 25-01-2001 to 25-07-2018

Comment: The data is shown as between right? I mean `25-01-2001` ,  `25-02-2001`, ...,  `25-07-2018`

Comment: yes you need to convert the date to timestamp as i did above

Comment: Ok, one by one?

Comment: it is just conversion of date... One by one does not matter here

Answer (score 1):

It might work

```
db.under_writing_limits.find(
        {25 :new Date(verification_start_time) },
        { customer_id: 1, verification_start_time: 1,address_scoring: 1 }
    )
```

Comment: `File "<ipython-input-19-050b3443a4da>", line 3
    {25 :new Date(verification_start_time) },
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`